# BinaryString in Ruby with single bit for bool representation

Tags: ruby, udp, bit-manipulation, pack

I'm looking at constructing a UDP packet as per a protocol that specifies the layout of the packet to the bit level, and I'm not sure how to go about this in Ruby. My understanding is the `pack` and `unpack` functions for arrays would be the most appropriate.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack

The array documentation lists a whole bunch of different arguments that can be used with `pack`, but I'm not sure how to pack a boolean value as a single bit.

[image: 1]

The format I'm trying to achieve looks like that.

My understanding was that I would be able to do something like:

```
[size_int, origin_as_int, tagged, addressable, protocol_int, source_int].pack "v1????V1"
```

Where the questions marks indicate where I'm not sure how to represent the fields. I could do something like

```
binary_string = ""
binary_string += "%02b" % origin_as_int
binary_string += (tagged ? "1" : "0")
binary_string += (addressable ? "1" : "0")
binary_string += "%012b" % protocol_int

munged_stuff = binary_string.to_i(2)
[size_int, munged_stuff, source_int].pack "v2V1"
```

I suppose? Feels kind of bad, though.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used the headache-inducing methods [Array#pack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [String#unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-unpack), but after reading their docs they actually seem quite straightforward, at least for what I assume are the more commonly-used directives, such as `'C'`, `'S'`, `'L'`, `'Q'`, `'B'`, `'b'`, `'A'` and `'a'`.

I believe you can do something like this:

```
size_int      = 123             # C (0 to 2**8-1 => 255)
origin_as_int = "10"            # B2
tagged        = "1"             # B1
addressable   = "0"             # B1
protocol_int  = "010011001011"  # B12  
source_int    = 2361            # S (0 to 2**16-1 => 65535)

template = %| C B2 B1 B1 B12 S |.delete(' ')
  #=> "CB2B1B1B12S"

s = [size_int, origin_as_int, tagged, addressable, protocol_int,
     source_int].pack(template)
  #=> "{\x80\x80\x00L\xB09\t"

s.unpack(template)
  #=> [123, "10", "1", "0", "010011001011", 2361]
```

Comment: Similar to what I had but much more elegant, thank you